# Display MathJax expression on the same line of the statement

Tags: mathjax

see the coding snippet

```
<div id="MathOutput" class="output">What will be the output of  $${x^2}$$</div>
```

This displays the string "What will be the output of" on a single line and the expression on the second line [image]

How can I make the expression display beside the line in continuation?

Answer (score 7):

Use `$x^2$` or `\(x^2\)` rather than `$$x^2$$`.  The single dollars are for in-line math equations, and double dollars are for equations displayed on a separate line.

Single dollars are not enabled by default in MathJax, so if you want to use those, you need to include them in the `inlineMath` array in your `tex2jax` block in your MathJax configuration.  See the [tex2jax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html) for details.

Comment: I tried with your solution, but the expression isn't rendered now.
Check the screenshot @ http://prntscr.com/4wxytx

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant here on the MathJax-enabed SE sites.  There are two ways to get in-line math (and display math), one is `$...$` and the other is `\(...\)`.  The single dollars are disabled by default because they can appear in normal text too easily.  So if you want to used them, you need to enable them in your configuration.  I modified my answer above to indicate this.

Comment: Check the screenshot attached. Still unable to make it in a single line. http://prntscr.com/52w7eu

Comment: Can you link to the page for your screen shot?  Your MathJax configuration could be the source of the problem, and it is not possible to tell from a screen shot.  We need to be able to see the code in the page and the MathJax configuration.